# Bash script to merge two files if they start with the same 4 characters

Tags: bash, sh, cat

When I tested the code on a directory that only had 100 files everything executed quickly.  But the actual directory has 20k files and everything slows to a halt.   Example files are 0001.txt 0001.doc 0002.txt 0002.doc, etc.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check if a directory name is provided as an argument
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 directory"
  exit 1
fi

dir="$1"

# Check if the directory exists and is accessible
if [ ! -d "$dir" ]; then
  echo "Error: $dir is not a directory or does not exist"
  exit 1
fi

# Create directories for combined
mkdir -p "$dir/Combined"


# Loop through all files in the directory
for file1 in "$dir"/*
do
  for file2 in "$dir"/*
  do
    # Get the first four characters of each file
    first_four1=$(basename "$file1" | cut -c1-4)
    first_four2=$(basename "$file2" | cut -c1-4)
    
 # Check if the files have the same first four characters and aren't the same file
    if [[ "$first_four1" == "$first_four2" && "$file1" != "$file2" ]]
    then
      # Combine the two files and move them to the "Combined" directory
      combined_filename="$dir/Combined/$first_four1.txt"
      cat "$file2" "$file1" > "$combined_filename"
      #echo "Combined $file1 and $file2 into $combined_filename"

    # Read the file contents
    input_file=$(cat $combined_filename)

    # extract the value of the "meta tag" attribute using awk

    meta_tag=$(awk -F'content="' '/og:title/{print substr($2, 1, length($2)-13)}' "$combined_filename" | cut -d '"' -f 1)

    # Replace any special characters in the title value with underscores
    safe_title=$(echo "$meta_tag" | tr -c '[:alnum:]' '_')


    # Rename the input file with the safe title
    mv "$combined_filename" "${combined_filename%.txt} - ${safe_title}.txt"
      
      rm "$file1" "$file2"
    fi
  done
done
```

I'm learning to code and can't find the looping issue.

When the code runs, it finds the first two files with the similar names and combines them and writes them to the proper directory as expected, but then it takes forever to find the next pair.

Comment: Avoid subshells within loops -- period. That is the death knell for shell performance. Look at your script. You have nested loops and within your inner loop you spawn **12** subshells (every command-substitution, utility call and don't forget each pipe, requires a separate process). Yes that will bring performance to its knees for any significant number of files. Whenever you run into a situation like this -- it tells you you are taking the wrong approach to solving the problem.

Comment: You're doing O(n^2) operations instead of O(n) by nesting your loops. I don't know if i matters but it looks like the order that you combine files is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid, if possible, using nested loops in shell scripts, which can lead to performance issues. The following is one way a more efficient script could be written, assuming filenames don't contain newline characters (not a 100% safe assumption):

```
dir=$1
cd "$dir" || exit

printf '%s\n' * | cut -c1-4 | uniq -d |
    while IFS= read -r prefix; do
        cat "$prefix"* > Combined/"$prefix".txt
    done
```

Answer (score 0):

If your files are truly matched by the first four characters in their base names, then you might be able to convert your nested loop into a single loop.  Further, some optimization might be achieved by utilizing BASH parameter expansions rather than sub shells to `cut`, `basename`, etc...:

Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir="${1:-sample_dir}"

# single loop over .txt files in $dir
for i in "$dir"/*.txt ; do 
    # bash parameter expansion rather than subshell to basename
    txt="${i##*/}"   
    
    # bash parameter expansion rather than subshell to cut
    ffour="${txt:0:4}"   

    # bash glob to get array of .doc files with same first four
    list=( "$dir/${ffour}"*.doc )  

    # verify that list contains only one file
    if [[ "${#list[@]}" -ne 1 ]] ; then
        echo "Too many .doc files for $ffour"
        exit 1
    fi 

    # extract last item as .doc file
    doc="${list[-1]}" 
    echo "$txt and ${doc##*/}"

    # combine files, extract meta tag, rename combined file, etc...

done
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing functionally wrong with your loop. Your code is just awfully inefficient.

1. It loops all files twice in order to find a match. You said there are 20k files. So essentially, your code loops 400 millions times.
2. Using pipe in loop is time consuming. You need to restructure your code more wisely.

For example, this command may take 2 secs to complete.

```
ls /folder/with/20k/files | cut -c1-4
```

While this command could take 10 mins to finish.

```
for file in /folder/with/20k/files; do
    echo "$file" | cut -c1-4
done
```

This is why you saw the first two files got merged right away. Then the code was like halted because it was looping thru the rest of 20K files, doing meaningless comparisons.

So come to suggestions:

1. Reduce the number of loops. If your files are mostly paired, this will reduce loop number to 10K (compare to original 400 millions)

```
ls | cut -c1-4 | uniq | while read -r first_four; do
    ...
done
```

2. I see no need to write a combined file in middle point, as it will eventually be replaced by final file. IO is time consuming. Combined file content can be saved to variable instead.

```
input_file=$(cat "$file2" "$file1")
```

3. The meta tag part uses 3 pipes (awk/cut/tr). Revising it shall also greatly improve loop efficiency. You didn't provide actual file so I couldn't provide suggestions. Good luck on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can greatly improve the efficiency of your script by looping over either the `.doc` files or `.txt` files and concatenating with the corresponding file. You can further improve the efficiency by using builtin parameter expansions to remove the extension rather than spawning another subshell for `cut`.

Your goal is to validate both the `.doc` and `.txt` files *exist* and are *non-empty* using `test -s` and then concatenating both into a temp file, remove the originals and then `mv -f` the combined temporary file to the `.txt` file name. If both files don't exist or one is empty, simply skip concatenating and log an error message.

You can do that with something similar to:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

srcdir="${1:-.}"              ## directory is first parameter [. default]
tmpname="tmp$(date +%N).txt"  ## temporary file name to use

cd "$srcdir" || {   ## change to directory or exit
  printf "error: dir not found or no read permission: %s\n" "$srcdir" >&2
  exit 1
}

## loop over each .doc
for fname in *.doc; do
  txtname="${fname%.doc}.txt"           ## use builtin to get .txt name
  
  ## validate both .doc and .txt are non-empty or continue
  if [ ! -s "$fname" ] || [ ! -s "$txtname" ]
  then
    printf "error: no corresponding .txt for %s\n" "$fname" >&2
    continue
  fi
  
  cat "$fname" "$txtname" > "$tmpname"  ## concatenate .doc & .txt
  rm -f "$fname" "$txtname"             ## remove .doc & .txt
  mv -f "$tmpname" "$txtname"           ## mv combined to .txt name
done
```

(**note:** it is simpler just to change to the directory containing the files you wish to combine rather than manipulating the path portion of the full pathname)

**Example Use/Output**

Say you have a directory with:

```
$ ls -1 merge
01.doc
01.txt
02.doc
02.txt
03.doc
03.txt
04.doc
04.txt
05.doc
05.txt
06.doc
06.txt
07.doc
07.txt
08.doc
08.txt
09.doc
09.txt
10.doc
10.txt
```

Where each `.doc` file contains `'a'` and each `.txt` file contains `'b'`, e.g.

```
$ cat merge/01.doc
a
```

```
$ cat merge/01.txt
b
```

Running the script, e.g.

```
$ bash merge-doc-txt.sh merge
```

Results in the `merge` directory now containing:

```
$ ls -1 merge
01.txt
02.txt
03.txt
04.txt
05.txt
06.txt
07.txt
08.txt
09.txt
10.txt
```

Where each of the files contains the contents of the merged `.doc` and `.txt` files, e.g.

```
$ cat merge/01.txt
a
b
```

This should provide a significant speed improvement. Let me know if you have questions.